# 403 Forbidden Home page

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I uploaded a Laravel project, and all is okay except for the home page, which returns a 403 error. The URL mysiteweb.fr causes this error. I have another route which named home that refers to the same method in the HomeController.

Here are my routes:

```php
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('/');
```

Here is my index method controller

```php
public function index() {
   return view('home');
}
```

So, when I call the URL `mysiteweb.fr/home`, all is good. But when I call `mysiteweb.fr`, the result is ERROR 403

Here is my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
    # Force HTTPS Redirection
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysiteweb.fr/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I have given good permissions to folders. (755)

Thanks for your help.

I put most of my folders in 755 permissions.

Comment: try this route  `Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
}); `

Comment: I just tried this but I always get 403 ERROR

Comment: And I did the same method whit the home route and it's working with the home route, so the code is OK but the problem comes from elsewhere

Comment: I think it is not a good way to named route with ` \` try another name like `home.index`

Comment: I tried to put 'index' as the route name but it changes nothing

Comment: Maybe the prooblem comes from an autorisation just for the URL ' / ' ?

Comment: The problem was that permissions given through ssh terminal wasn't effectives. I used PUTTY to put permissions on my folders and I saw the good permissions on IONOS but nothing was changing. When I gave the same permissions through my FTP Client (Filezilla), it resolved my problem. Effectivly, permissions with PUTTY was given fastly (0-10sec) while it took like 15/20 min with ftp client.

Thanks for your help !